# How i can pass real data from my javascript function-script to javascript chart js

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, live

> this is the chart i want to insert my live int data (counter) from python flask server to the chart i want it to be a live upload chart the data are live but i cant insert the to the chart it disappears

```html
   

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

> live data go to  test class as a count number 1,2 ,3 ,4 but i  cant import that result to chartjs so i wanted to ask how can i take the sensor reading information and create a live chart
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
>
> <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <title>Flask App</title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>
>
>   <div id='test'></div>
>
> <script>
>   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
>
>     const getSensorReading = function() {
>       fetch(`http://${location.host}/update`)  // send request to route /update
>         .then((resp) => resp.json())
>         .then(function(response) {
>           document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =response.data.toFixed(1);
>       });
>     }
>
>     getSensorReading();
>
>     setInterval(getSensorReading, 1000); 
>    //request for update every 1 second
>   });
>
>
>   </script>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: #! /usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

count = 10

# this route only handle the rendering of index.html
@app.route("/main")
def main():
   return render_template('index.html')

# this route handling the request send to the /update uri
@app.route("/update")
def update():
    global count
    count=count+1
    val = 500
 
    templateData  = {'data' : count}
    return jsonify(templateData), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run( debug=True)

Comment: You should at least specify what data you have and how you want to display it. You can edit your first post to do so.

Comment: @LennartThamm Its my first time i post in stackoverflow and im sorry for the hard readed post becasue i couldnt post flask-python code i commended it  so i get from flask a int counter and  i want it to put that counter in the chart js data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im trying to insert the data that provides getSensorfunction into the data of the chart so it will change automaticly and update without page reload or press button the data from the chart my function getsensorreading give in real time data as a div i want return it into a variable that i can put into the data: [] of the chart is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps for building this would be along these lines:

1. Plot your first data point with chartjs. Add this point, do not care (too much about the live data). You can find an example on how to build a simple linechart here: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/2.6.0/charts/line/basic.html. Look into the html, there is a script tag before the closing body tag, that builds the chart.
2. Keep a reference to the chart. In the example they do that by assigning to the window object. So assigning like this: `window.myLineChat = new Chart(container, config)`. In a browser, the window is the global namespace, so it is not super clean doing so (but probably the least troublesome in the beginning).
3. Because you have a reference to the chart, you can now update it. If the reference is in the global namespace (your window) you can access it right away, without passing any data - as long as you have already defined the chart. So each time you get new data, you just pass it to your chart.
   See: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

If you use window.myLineChart, the function will change:

```js
function addData(label, data) {
    window.myLineChart.data.labels.push(label);
    window.myLineChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Comment: sorry that changes completly the code i wanted to find how the <div id='test'> result can get into data: chart is it possible i wanted to be simple and thanks for awnsering @lennart Thamm

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to build a linechart the code will naturally get a lot more difficult than just displaying the value. You cannot pass the div#test into the chart. Any approach to this will look somewhat like the outline I posted.